# Can I use SQL to edit a piece of a record in a group of rows?

Tags: sql, paradox

The records of one column in my table have a letter/dash prefix (B-290151626). I need to remove the letter/dash without changing the rest of the record, and do this for 1700 rows.

This is for the Paradox database (yes I know it's old) and I have a simple SQL editor window to work with inside the application. I can select all the records I need to edit, grouped by their letter prefix.

Here's a view of the table:
[image: View of table]

Comment: Do you have access to functions like `SUBSTRING` and `LEN`? If so, is something like `UPDATE table SET field = SUBSTRING(field, 3, LEN(field) - 2)` an option?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I tried this but get  'SQL Error: Invalid use of Keyword'  I think I am limited to commands supported by SQL-92 and I am still researching what commands are included in this set. I'll update when I get a reliable list of usable functions.

Comment: I finally got it after tweaking the syntax a bit. SUBSTRING is supported. Thank you  @ChinaSyndrome for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table 
SET BookingID = SUBSTRING(BookingID , 3, LEN(BookingID ) - 2) 
where  substring(BookingID,0,1) ='B'
```